# How to combine records from different table into one record set with count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code

```
SELECT 
    dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType, 
    COUNT(dbo.tbl2.CertType) AS   Quantity
FROM 
    dbo.tbl3 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl3.RequestNo = dbo.tbl2.RequestNo 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbl1 ON dbo.tbl2.CertType = dbo.tbl1.RecId
GROUP BY 
    dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType
```

And it returns this result:

```
RecId CertType   Quantity
1     Clearance         4
2     Permit            0
```

It only counts the quantity from `tbl3` but I want it to count also the records from `tbl4` but just don't know how to add code for it.

Note: `tbl4` has the same format with `tlb3`. thanks for your help.

I want the result just like this:

```
RecId CertType   Quantity
1     Clearance         4
2     Permit            2
```

Comment: Change `dbo.tbl3` to `dbo.tbl4` in your statement.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam yes but it will only count the number of records in tbl4. What i want is to count the records of both tables and put it in Quantity Fields.

Comment: Check this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73053/combining-count-queries-into-one-table-row

Comment: simply add `tbl4` to your query, join it with `tbl3` on `RequestNo`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks but could you show me how to do it?and also i think it counts only tbl3 because of FROM tbl3,I wonder if we could add another FROM tbl4 for example and do the joins to tbl1 and tbl2 but just dont know how and where to put it.

Comment: ...`FROM dbo.tbl3 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl4 ON dbo.tbl3.RequestNo = dbo.tbl4.RequestNo 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl3.RequestNo = dbo.tbl2.RequestNo`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks again for your help but the result is 0 in Quantity of all CertType. The actual Quantity is 4 for tbl3 and 2 for tbl4.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables ddl + dml for sample data, so that people will be able to get the correct answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the [over](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx) clause would be useful. There is an example in the appropriate section in the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx) that uses the **count** command. Your case should become something like:

```
SELECT 
    t.RecId, t.CertType, 
    COUNT(t.CertType) over (partition by t.RecId) AS   Quantity
FROM 
    (SELECT   dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType
     FROM 
         dbo.tbl3 
         INNER JOIN dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl3.RequestNo = dbo.tbl2.RequestNo
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl1 ON dbo.tbl2.CertType = dbo.tblBasicPermitFeeSchedule.RecId
     UNION
     SELECT   dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType
     FROM         
         dbo.tbl4 
         INNER JOIN dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl4.RequestNo = dbo.tblRequests.RequestNo
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl1 ON dbo.tbl2.CertType = dbo.tbl1.RecId) t
GROUP BY 
    t.RecId, t.CertType
```

or something similar. I haven't tested it yet though, so it could be a bit different.

Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: I tried it but got this error: Column 'dbo.tbl2.CertType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Also i think it cannot count the Quantity in tbl4 because its FROM clause calls only tbl3.

Comment: I modified the query based on your other answer in which seemed like the records were counted separately for tbl3 and tbl4. This query should merge the answers and count them all (for tbl3 and tbl4 altogether). Check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got this solution that works for me.

```
SELECT   dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType, 
COUNT(dbo.tbl2.RequestNo)  AS   Quantity
FROM         dbo.tbl3 INNER JOIN 
         dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl3.RequestNo = dbo.tbl2.RequestNo
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.tbl1 ON dbo.tbl2.CertType = dbo.tblBasicPermitFeeSchedule.RecId                                          

 GROUP BY dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType

UNION
SELECT   dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType, 
COUNT(dbo.tbl2.RequestNo)  AS   Quantity
FROM         dbo.tbl4 INNER JOIN 
         dbo.tbl2 ON dbo.tbl4.RequestNo = dbo.tblRequests.RequestNo
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.tbl1 ON dbo.tbl2.CertType = dbo.tbl1.RecId                                          

 GROUP BY dbo.tbl1.RecId, dbo.tbl1.CertType
```

Thanks for all your ideas.